# Warning: ftp_get(): RETR

Tags: php, web

I am using this code:

```
   <?php
// connect and login to FTP server
$ftp_server = "ftp.example.com";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

$local_file = "local.zip";
$server_file = "server.zip";

// download server file
if (ftp_get($ftp_conn, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_ASCII))
  {
  echo "Successfully written to $local_file.";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error downloading $server_file.";
  }

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
?>
```

In order to get a specific file from a server.
I tried also using -

```
if (ftp_get($ftp_conn, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY))
```

insted of

```
if (ftp_get($ftp_conn, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_ASCII))
```

I kepp getting the error- 
 Warning: ftp_get(): RETR in myfile.php on line 13.

Please Help.

Comment: This cannot be the whole warning you get.

Comment: That is what I get. Maybe because Its on local server (Wamp).

Comment: There usually is something like "not understood" behind that warning...

Answer (score 0):

Shimon, when you send and `ftp_get`, you're sending an `RETR` command to the ftp server requesting the desired file. It seems that `RETR` is disabled on your FTP server. Try to get your file with your favorite FTP client to see if will work an tell us the result here. (Also, check if you have read permissions on that folder)

Comment: The server's company  that I work with says- "You can download the Merchandiser file from your account using any FTP client software. You must make sure that you use the get command to download the file. The mget command will not work. "

Comment: "The files that are visible in your FTP directory are the ones with the .lmp extension. This extension represents functions, not actual files, and you should not attempt to download them. Although the files with .gz may not be visible in the FTP directory, you will still be able to download them using FTP commands such as:  
get file.gz".I don't know how to use get on WinSCP...

Comment: the command to use get on WinSCP is: get <file> [ [ <file2> ... ] <directory>\[ <newname> ] ]

Have you tried that ?

Comment: I don't know where to add the text. 
On coomends->Open Terminal I am getting an error while using get .